# Stumped - How would I solve this probability question?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This question was merely a fun online math problem to see how many people could solve it, but I haven't been able to since last week and it's beginning to drive me nuts. The question:

A man has $7$ math books, $4$ history books and $5$ fiction books. What are the number of ways he can arrange $3$ math books, $2$ history books and $3$ fiction books on a shelf?

Now initially, I looked at the problem thinking "this can't be that hard, the shelf can only contain $3$ math, $2$ history and $3$ fiction books right? I calculated the number of possible ways he could arrange those $8$ books on the shelf then realized it was a little more complicated than that.. Each book is different, so from the $7$ math books there's all the possible ways he could arrange those alone, then the ways he could arrange the $2$ of $4$ history books and the $3$ of $5$ fiction books..

So using the $nCr$ formula for combinations, I came up with:

\begin{align*}
7C3 & = 35\\  
4C2 & = 6\\  
5C3 & = 10  
\end{align*}
Then this is where I got stumped. Am I supposed to multiply them all together to get $2,100$ total combinations? (It told me this was incorrect) or do I start calculating further possibilities IE from the $35$ possible math book combinations, I can only have $3$ etc?

I did some other crazy calculations that made absolutely no sense so I probably won't share those. It's been a while since I've done any sort of probability so if someone could explain to me how this problem is solved I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: The user [Danny Cryer](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/252807/danny-cryer) would like to know the URL of the website where you saw that problem. There may be other interesting problems there. Could you help him out by adding the URL to your question?

Comment: Just curious, why is this question tagged probability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By saying we are "arranging" the books on a shelf, the order usually matters. So my calculations assume that the order of the books matters.

To do this, first we choose the math books, which can be done in ${7 \choose 3}$ ways. Then we choose the history books, which can be done in ${4 \choose 2}$ ways. Then we choose the fiction books, which can be done in ${5 \choose 3}$ ways.

Then we arrange the order of the $8$ books we chose. This can be done in $8!$ ways.

The number of each of those choices is independent of the other choices, so the total count is the product of all those counts. Therefore our total count is

$${7 \choose 3}\cdot {4 \choose 2}\cdot {5 \choose 3}\cdot 8!$$
$$=35\cdot 6\cdot 10\cdot 40320$$
$$=84,672,000$$

This seems like a large number, but remember that this is small compared to the number of ways of arranging all $16$ books on that shelf, namely
$$16!=20,922,789,888,000$$

Comment: This explanation was fantastic and really helped me understand the steps required to solve it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways to choose the books is given by
$$ {7 \choose 3}   {4 \choose 2}  {5 \choose 3} $$
The way to arrange $8$ books in a row is given by ( assuming all the math/etc books are different)
$$8!$$
Thus the number of possible out comes is given by
$$  8 !\left( {7 \choose 3}   {4 \choose 2}  {5 \choose 3} \right ) $$
Where we read the ``choose" notation as
$$ { n \choose k }= \frac{ n!}{k! (n-k)!}$$

Comment: You should as well multiply those binomial coefficients.

Comment: Also, its said in the post that all books are different.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** First compute how many possibilities you have of choosing 3 math books out of 7, 2 history books out of 4 and 3 fiction books out of 5. Now multiply by the number of ways you can place 8 books on a shelf.